# Wrong Y coordinate from TextView on Bitmap using Canvas.drawText

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Please help me with my problem or at least give me advice.
I have ImageView with overlayed TextView. The user can drag text to any position on the image. After, I want to save the image with text at chosen position.

Layout (TextView add dynamically to root element):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**All problem in Y coordinate is always wrong**. I'm try 2 function to find X and Y coordinates.

First:

```
public float[] getPosition(ImageView imageView, TextView textView) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
float[] coord = {textView.getX(), textView.getY()};
matrix.mapPoints(coord);

return coord;
}
```

and better one, using this function give you accurate X.

```
private float[] getCoordinates(ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, float x, float y){
    float projectedX = (float) ((double)x * ((double)bm.getWidth()/(double)iv.getWidth()));
    float projectedY = (float) ((double)y * ((double)bm.getHeight()/(double)iv.getHeight()));

    return new float[]{projectedX, projectedY};
}
```

Any advice? Y always higher than the desired position when Canvas draw text.

Here is my code to save data for Canvas.drawText:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    TextView textView = (TextView)relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    bundle.putString("text", ((TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString());
                    bundle.putFloatArray("coord", getPosition(imageView,textView));
                    bundle.putFloat("size", size*scale);
                    new AsyncDraw().execute(bundle);
```

And after in AsyncTask:

```
     Bundle bundle = bundles[0];
        String text = bundle.getString("text");
        float[] coord = bundle.getFloatArray("coord");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(oriented);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(bundle.getFloat("size"));
        canvas.drawText(text, coord[0],coord[1],paint);
```

Comment: whats wrong with method #1? it should work (provided of course textView.getX() and textView.getY() are correct locations)

Comment: don't know, first metod give me wrong Y and X coordinates

Comment: check [this](http://pastebin.com/4h6WvGYj) code, try to click on the top-left corner of the image and bottom-right one, watch the logcat

Comment: Hello, here is result: 
Top-left: onTouch image bounds Rect(0, 0 - 640, 480) 
onTouch mapped point 0.0, 2.3254395 
Bottom-right: onTouch image bounds Rect(0, 0 - 640, 480) onTouch mapped point 637.33887, 472.40454

Comment: so it works: top-left results in nearly [0, 0] while bottom-right results in nearly [640, 480], why are you saying that inverse mapping does not work?

Comment: of course if you click in the centre of your image you will get: [320, 240]

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/2f0645x.jpg here is why

Comment: no idea what you mean, i gave you a simple code that maps image view coordinates to physical image pixel coordinates, how you wil use it is a different story...

Comment: I did not want to hurt you. But now I can't understand why Canvas draw text indented by Y axis.

Comment: how can i know? i dont see any `Canvas#drawText` in the code you posted

Comment: Can I ask you in chat?

Comment: i cannot answer more than that as i have no idea what your code looks like

Comment: I added the code, please look. Now I see the problem, but not so good in painting to resolve it.

Comment: But how I see, need to add textView.getY() + textView.getHeight(). So baseline be at bottom :)

Comment: yes, more or less...

Comment: Please write an answer and I approve it!

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping the height values to your device screen metrics using [TypedValue.applyDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) method